# Is there a way to mirror to HDMI display on FileVault login screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, filevault, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro Retina & Mavericks, with FileVault 2 enabled. I also mirror to an HDMI display, but it doesn't show anything on FileVault 2 login. This is an issue, because I'd like to get a docking station where MacBook is actually closed (clamshell mode). But then I can't see the login screen. Is there a solution? As far I've seen at this point, I need to boot up and login with the laptop open; and then close it and put it in the dock.

Answer (score -1):

Is the laptop plugged in? If not, it has to be plugged in in order to output to a display while closed